# How to save contents of an encrypted file in C#

Tags: c#, file, console, aes

So I am attempting to write an application that allows a user to encrypt and decrpyt files using AES and a password of their choice. However, the problem is FileStream is not allowing me to copy the encrypted message (which the user makes in a word or notepad document) then points the program to where they saved it.

The issue I am having, `FileStream` is unable to write the encrypted contents to the file, saying Severity

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IO.Stream'    CMDUniversalPGP C:\Users\keife\source\repos\CMDUniversalPGP\CMDUniversalPGP\Program.cs  106 N/A

Here is the code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration;
using com.sun.beans.decoder;
using System.IO.Compression;
using com.sun.tools.@internal.xjc.reader.gbind;
using org.omg.CORBA_2_3.portable;

namespace CMDUniversalPGP
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Windows Universal PGP! Here you will compose emails or files to be encrypted by me. You will create the password. Program C 2020 Keifmeister.");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("Press 1 to encrypt a file, 2 to decrypt one.");
            int action = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


            switch (action)
            {

                case 1:
                    try
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("");
                        Console.WriteLine("I will now launch Microsoft Word. I may only find office if it's installed in C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\root\\Office16. If it's not installed I will launch notepad. Please compose your message in a new word or notepad document then point me to where it is, I will encrypt it for you. You may then send the encrypted file via email attchment. Only those with the password will be able to open.Please remember when emailing the sending and reiceving email addresses as well as subject are  still viewable. Cheers.");
                        
                        Process.Start("C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\root\\Office16\\WINWORD");
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("I could not find word, so launching notepad.");
                        Process.Start("C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\notepad.exe");


                    }


                    Console.WriteLine("Please point me to the saved file.");
                    string sourceFile = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("Please point me to where you want the encrypted file saved.");
                    string encFile = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter the encrypted file name and extension.");
                    string encDir  = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your desired password.");
                    string password = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());



                    void EncryptFile(string sourceFile, string encFile)
                    {

                        try
                        
                            {

                                DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(encDir);
                                if (!info.Exists)
                                {
                                    info.Create();
                                }

                                string path = Path.Combine (encDir, encFile);
                                using (FileStream outputFileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
                                {
                                
                                }
                            

                            UnicodeEncoding UE = new UnicodeEncoding();
                            byte[] key = UE.GetBytes(password);

                            string cryptFile = encFile;
                            FileStream fsCrypt = new FileStream(cryptFile, FileMode.Create);

                            RijndaelManaged RMCrypto = new RijndaelManaged();

                            CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fsCrypt,
                                RMCrypto.CreateEncryptor(key, key),
                                CryptoStreamMode.Write);

                            FileStream fsIn = new FileStream(sourceFile, FileMode.Open);
                            
                           
                            int data;
                            while ((data = fsIn.ReadByte()) != -1)
                                cs.WriteByte((byte)data);


                            fsIn.Close();
                            cs.Close();
                            fsCrypt.Close();

//This is where the error is occuring, thank you.

                            FileStream.CopyTo(encFile);
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Could not enrypt.");
                            Console.WriteLine(""); 
                            Console.WriteLine("Do you want to email the encryoted file? Type yes and I will open your default mail client and email account with it attached to a new email. If not type no and I will exit.");
                        }
                    }
                    break;

                case 2:
                    try
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Please point me to the encrypted file.");
                        string sourceFile2 = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
                        Console.WriteLine("Please point me to where you want the decrypted file saved.");
                        string decFile = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
                        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the password.");
                        string passworddec = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());


                        {
                            byte[] passwords = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(passworddec);
                            byte[] salt = new byte[32];
                            using (FileStream fsCrypt = new FileStream(sourceFile2, FileMode.Open))
                            {
                                fsCrypt.Read(salt, 0, salt.Length);
                                RijndaelManaged AES = new RijndaelManaged();
                                AES.KeySize = 256;//aes 256 bit encryption c#
                                AES.BlockSize = 128;//aes 128 bit encryption c#
                                var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwords, salt, 50000);
                                AES.Key = key.GetBytes(AES.KeySize / 8);
                                AES.IV = key.GetBytes(AES.BlockSize / 8);
                                AES.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                                AES.Mode = CipherMode.CFB;
                                using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(fsCrypt, AES.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                                {
                                    using (FileStream fsOut = new FileStream(decFile, FileMode.Create))
                                    {
                                        int read;
                                        byte[] buffer = new byte[1048576];
                                        while ((read = cryptoStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                                        {
                                            Console.WriteLine("The decrypted message:");
                                            Console.WriteLine("");
                                            fsOut.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Could not decrypt. Possibly file is too large or password is incorrect.");

                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The line `FileStream.CopyTo(encFile);` is where the error happens.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What do you want the statement `FileStream.CopyTo(encFile);` to do?

Comment: catch ( Exception ex ) { Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace); Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); will help you to find out what causes error.

Comment: Might be the link helpful for you http://csharphelper.com/blog/2014/09/encrypt-or-decrypt-files-in-c/

Comment: To answer Klaus Gutter, I want it to copy the encrypted text to the new document. Thanks very much all.

Comment: I think you'd benefit from having written your algorithm out in comments before trying to write it in c#; surely you should have 3 streams - a file reading stream, a file writing stream and an encrypting stream connected to the file writing one?

Comment: The Stream is taking a file that already exists, running an encryption algorithm, then saving it as a new file. Thanks.